# In typescript, extends 'Request' and 'Response' interfaces from express while maintaining generic type safety

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

With typescript, I can use generic to type my requests and responses like so: `(req: Request<MyParamsType, {}, MyBodyType>, res: Response<MyResponseType>)`.
Which ensure ensure for example that the correct type is passed to `res.send()`.

I have a util function named `sendOr404(body)` that I add to the response object which passes the given object to `res.send` or send a 404 code if it is null.

I am trying to extends the `Response` response interface to incorporate this method. I know that I can do it like that:

```js
declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Response {
            sendOr404(body: any): void,
        }
    }
}
```

However, this way I lose type safety since `body` accept any type.

I tried to add generic to my interface definition:

```js
export interface Response<TRes = {}> {
    sendOr404(object: TRes | null): void,
}
```

but it doesn't works, `TRes` always gets inferred as `{}`

```js
interface MyResponseType {
  data: { /*... */}
}

app.post('/example', (req: Request<MyParamsType, {}, MyBodyType>, res: Response<MyResponseType>) => {
  res.sendOr404({}) // no error
})
```

Comment: What's the version of `express` are you using?

Comment: Version ^4.18.2